# Failure replacing URL pattern with sed

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed

I am attempting to change 1 URL in a config file with another using sed and I fail for different reasons.
The URL I am trying to replace is:

```
#define API_PRODUCTION @"https://api.mything.com/v2.0/services"
```

with:

```
#define API_PRODUCTION @"https://qaapp3.mything.com/20151115_apiv2/services"
```

I tried escaping with \ before every / and different methods but failed for "unterminated substitute pattern" or for " bad flag in substitute command: 'a'"
Seems so easy, yet I cannot nail it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show the `sed` command too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to escape `/` if you use another character as separator:

```
$ cat testfile
#define API_PRODUCTION @"https://api.mything.com/v2.0/services"
$ sed -e 's,https://api.mything.com/v2.0/services,https://qaapp3.mything.com/20151115_apiv2/services,' testfile
#define API_PRODUCTION @"https://qaapp3.mything.com/20151115_apiv2/services"
```

Comment: Alright, this seems to make the change successfully but for some reason it's not saved because I see the file unchanged. I do it with the correct user I think

Comment: @PavelZagalsky, You need to use `-i` option to change the file in-place.

Answer (score 1):

`% sed -ie s/api/qapp3/ filename.txt
define API_PRODUCTION @"https://qapp3.mything.com/v2.0/services"`

I'm on NetBSD, so your sed may be different, Pavel.

Comment: Hey, where in the command should I mention the file I am editing? I tried it but it tells me I didn't define the file. I'm on Mac OS, so it's OK I guess

Comment: Ok, should be in the end I figured, for some reason it shows that the file was changed but it actually didn't..

Comment: if you add -i to your command, sed alters the file without issue

Comment: Just tried that, doesn't help. Changed the file permission to 777 as well. Weird :/ I do not see any error whatsoever